# How can I configure my chrome driver path in selenium in order to run tests on another machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new to writing test scripts and I am trying to figure out how to make my chrome driver on my local, work on the remote branch in git. If someone were to try to run my test case on their machine, they wouldn't be able to since my chrome path is on my local machine. How can I fix this? This is what I currently have in my test script to run on my machine.

```
System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\vanes\\eclipseworkspace\\OwnProject\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

With webdrivermanager you might not care about this.

`webdrivermanager` automatically downloads the required chromedriver based on your OS.

remove this line:

```
System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\vanes\eclipseworkspace\OwnProject\Drivers\chromedriver.exe");
```

and use:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

add this dependency:

maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or gradle:

```
implementation 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.1.0'
```

---

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Comment: Thanks for your help Max, I am going to have to scrap the project and do it over as I did something with the driver configuration and I don't know how to undo it and now nothing is working. I was using System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , readconfig.getChromePath()); Is this another way to do it as well?

Comment: @VanessaMitchell `webdrivermanager` library sets `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"` programmatically instead of you. So you shouldn't have been set it yourself anymore.